# React update values

Tags: react-hooks

I've got problem with my first react app.
I've set the interval function which counts down from 10 to 0 and after the 0 is reached the interval is cleared. At least it should work like this, but when I console log the time it's always 10 (even though it renders properly in the browser - the value is getting smaller), so it never jumps to the else statement.
What should I do to fix this problem?

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Timer = () => {

  let flag = true;
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (flag) {
            setInterval(counter, 500);
        }
    }

  const counter = () => {
    if (time > 0) {
      console.log(time);
      setTime(time => time - 1);
    } else {
      console.log('out');
      clearInterval(timer);
     }
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <div>{time}</div>
      <button className="start" onClick={handleClick}>START</button>
    </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Timer />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Where does `setTime` come from? Create a minimal, complete, reproducible example

Comment: @slideshowp2 i edited my post. Is it clear now for you?

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. Thank you guys for trying to help :) Snippet below:

```js
const {useState} = React;
const {useEffect} = React;
const Timer = () => {

  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(10);

  const handleClick = () => {
      setFlag(!flag);
  }

    useEffect(() => {
        function counter () {
            if (time > 0) {
                setTime(time => time - 1)
            }  
        }

       if (flag) {
           console.log('a');
           const interval = setInterval(counter, 1000)
           return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, [flag, time]);

    return(
        <div>
            <div>{time}</div>
            <button className="start" onClick={handleClick} >START</button>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timer />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: you can approve your own question to guide people who may have the same problem